# PHP function with looping variabel

Tags: php

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$2; $i++){
    function writeMsg() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    } 
}
```

I want to output write code

```
 //function writeMsg1(){

//}
```

and

```
//function writeMsg2(){
//}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you will have to be more explicit...

Comment: don't redeclare a function within a loop. put the function outside the loop and just call it from within

Comment: What does the loop have to do with the commented code you showed? Are you asking if you can define a function `writeMsg$i`?

Comment: @barmar yes i want writeMsg$i

Comment: You have your answer below

Comment: Please clarify your question and request that it be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define functions in a loop like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {

$code = <<<EOD
function writeMsg{$i}() {
  echo 'Hello World!';
}
EOD;

eval($code);
}

writeMsg1();
```

It outputs:

```
Hello World!
```

This code uses a [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (`<<<EOD EOD;`) to define the function and the [`eval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function which evaluates the code.